# How to replace '/' with '/\' using sed in shell scripting

Tags: shell, sed, devops

I am trying to replace

`prakash/annam/DevOps` ---> `prakash/\annam/\Devops`

I am using this:

```
sed "s/'[//]''///\\/g"
```

Unfortunately, it is not giving the required output can anyone please help with this!!!

Comment: An example of the data you're working with and an example of how you want it to
look after processing will help people answer the question for you. Since then
1) there is no ambiguity and 2) people can copy the examples and experiment
with it to build a good answer. Cheers!

Comment: Do you want ``/\`` or `\/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a separator other than slash:

```
$ sed 's#/#\\/#g' <<< "a/b/c"
a\/b\/c

$ sed 's#/#/\\#g' <<< "a/b/c"
a/\b/\c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed with `-i` flag to place in place changes to the file

## *nix

```
$ cat test 
prakash/annam/DevOps

$ sed -i 's/\//\/\\/g' test 

$ cat test
prakash/\annam/\DevOps
```

## MacOS

```
$ cat test 
prakash/annam/DevOps

$ sed -i '' 's/\//\/\\/g' test 

$ cat test
prakash/\annam/\DevOps
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sed -E 's/\//\/\\/g'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo "prakash/annam/DevOps" | sed -E 's/\//\/\\/g'
prakash/\annam/\DevOps
```

Comment: You might add value by explaining why your code works where the question fails (e.g. what's the purpose of `-E`). Consider an [edit].